# Set EditorState without the application state in Draft js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I want to update the Draft js Editor with some initial content. I know we can change `EditorState` using component state.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever I tried to change something in the Editor it's re rendering. This is causing some performance issue. Is there anyway I can set or change the Editor's state without changing the state. Something similar to this

```
EditorState.set(editorState); //here editorState is new editor state;
```

Any idea how to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by performance issue?

Comment: Typing in the editor is very slow.

Comment: There is no way to avoid re-rendering... whenever state changes it renders data again, that's the core of reactjs... can you brief what are the performance issues?

Comment: Do you have any jsfiddle demo of this ??

Comment: @SarathKumar as Lokesh Sanapalli mentioned that's how react works. I think because of setState are you facing any infinite call issue and that is what you mean performance issue?

Comment: @Think-Twice. I can totally understand concept of React. But here the Editor component contains some other form elements also. while editing in the editor resets the form elements and also little bit delay in typing. I know I can give state value to form elements. But I'm loosing focus each time change event fires.

Comment: It has a delay because you are passing event handler function and it’s stare value as props to editor component and that’s why you see delay.

Comment: @Think-Twice I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

After the two days of struggle, I found one useful [wysiwyg editor](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg) built on top of `Draft.js` with cool features. It has all the features given by `Draft.js`. We can load existing content using Editor's `refs`.

```
import {EditorState, convertFromRaw} from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';


class myEditor extends Component {

   componentDidMount(){
       //I have stored rawContent in  database
       let rawContent={"blocks":[{"key":"3ge2q","text":"Hello World!;","type":"header-three","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}};
       //Convert Raw to contentState
       let content=convertFromRaw(rawContent);
       let editorState=EditorState.createWithContent(content);
       this.refs.editor.editor.update(editorState); //Update the editor with updated content.
   }

    render(){
      <Editor
         ref="editor"
         wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
         editorClassName="template-editor"
         spellCheck={true}
         placeholder="Type something"
         onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange.bind(this)}
     />
  }
}
```